# How to prevent Broken Pipe error from stopping my shell script?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bioinformatics

I am new to AWS and cloud computing. I am using it bioinformatics work, mostly working on large file.
So I have this shell script and a large data file. It takes around like 4hrs+ time to execute the shell script on that data.

Due to some power issue my internet gets disconnected and on my linux terminal i get this error `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`.
By the time power comes back(usually take 5 mins) and i get reconnected to internet I get that error and my 3+ hrs are wasted .

So what i want is that even after the power issue my shell script should be running regardless of `Broken Pipe` error as my ec2 instance is still running.

Hope I am making sense. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your ec2 host closes connections that are idle for too long. You can update either your client or your ec2.

On your end try this:

```bash
echo "ServerAliveInterval 60" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

On your ec2, try this:

```bash
echo "ClientAliveInterval 60" | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

To learn more, type:

```bash
man 5 ssh_config
```

And read about `ServerAliveInterval`.

Comment: So 60 means 60 seconds right? Can I increase the timing?

Comment: Yeah, sure you can.